# Cell automatically phone powers down at certain location

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, power-on

Curiosity: at this location (False Creek, Vancouver, B.C.)

[Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/49%C2%B016'19.8"N+123%C2%B007'50.0"W/@49.2721667,-123.1311028,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m2!2m1!1sUnnamed+Road+Vancouver,+BC+V6Z+3G1+49.272158,+-123.130565!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d49.272165!4d-123.1305407?hl=en)

my girlfriend's cell phone (Android Moto X; Android 6 Marshmallow) automatically powers down (off).  When manually rebooting (turning on again), once powered up it automatically powers off, again.

If we move e.g. ~75-100 feet away, the phone operates normally?

This has happened on the two separate occasions that we tried to photograph some foliage, there.

What would cause this?

---

**Update** (Mar 10, 2019).  My gf and I returned to this spot (~5 months later): her with new phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Android 8 Oreo on a different wireless provider/account; GPS was ON).  This time, no problem.

That said, the GeoFence idea mentioned in the comments was likely the most reasonable explanation for the past behavior; perhaps that fence is no longer active.

Comment: Geo fence of some sort, is it happening with the GPS turned Off ?

Comment: As per Zillium's comment, please check whether the issue repeats after turning off GPS/Location and Mobile data/Wifi.

Comment: I would also check what the camera settings were when you attempted to take the photo. It could be that those specific camera settings for reasons like bug trigger a reboot and you may be thinking in terms of location dependent. Try to take a photo with the same settings elsewhere

Comment: Thank you for the comments: a geofence (I wasn't aware of those) seems likely.  Will update when we get a chance to return to that area.

Comment: @Zillinium: your suggestion seems to be the most probable answer.  Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.